# Android browser in background

Tags: android, asp.net

I am developing a web page for android browser. The page will authenticate users. I placed an iframe that will refresh every 10 minutes to keep the user logging while the page is open. However if the user switch to another application placing the web browser in the background, the refresh to keep logged in stops. So when the user switch back to the browser the session is lost and errors pop up from my ajax call in that page.....
How could i handle this scenario when the browser is sent to the background and keep the session alive?
thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png
Maybe you should reauthenticate user for example when onResume() method is fired

Answer (score 0):

Your app will call the `onPause()` and then the `onStop()` method of your Activity when it loses focus.

If you want to make things work in the background, you will have to do this in a `Service`. There is just no better way of doing background tasks.

Comment: he can't do it in a service, because the thing that needs to keep running in javascript associated with a particular browser session.

Comment: If he could somehow store the WebView in the Service, and then restart it in the `onResume()`?

Comment: the webview does run when the activity is resumed. the problem is that at this point the session has already been idle and is timed out.

Comment: Hi, I am talking about a web page in the browser not an application in the device, so i dont see a way to write a Service to handle my onResume web page in the browser